# Any idea how to change .innerHTML of A (link) tag so it won't be a link anymore?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I have difficult time to change a link tag (A) innerHTML so it won't be link anymore (well maybe not all the text would be a link or so...).

CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TEST</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<a href="">111<p>para</p></a>
<a href="">222<span>span</span></a>
<a href="">333<a href="">inside another link</a></a>

<script>
    var a = document.querySelectorAll('body a');
    //console.log(a);
    var newHTML = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        var childNodes = a[i].childNodes;
        //console.log(a[i]);
        //console.log(a[i].innerHTML);
        for (var y = 0; y < childNodes.length; y++)
        {
            childNodes[y].innerHTML += 'hey this is what we <li>are looking for</li>!'; // but it is still a link

        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I need to get all the links and combine them to an element (in chronological order). So it looks like:
*111para
222span
333inside another link*

and if the link content is '222', for example it should display additional text like "*`value we are looking for<li>NOT AS A LINK</li>!`*" (contain HTML tags!) like:

*111para*
*222value we are looking forNOT AS A LINK!span*
*333inside another link*

Of course this is a little bit more complicated cause links can have other tags inside them, so I just tried to copy the innerHTML of every link (so it looks VERY similar to the links it self - they appear where they should be, looks exactly the same, have same tags in them), and then try to combined them, BUT the "*`value we are looking for<li>NOT AS A LINK</li>!`*" message happens to be the link (cause... you guess it... it's inside the innerHTML of a link).

Any idea how to combine them (i prefer just to sum their innerHTML) - so I can add another chilNodes innerHTML together but the message "`value we are looking for<li>NOT AS A LINK</li>!`" won't be a link it self?

I even tried:
`a[i].outerHTML = a[i].innerHTML;` but then the link disappear :)
And I need href attribute to collect them so I can't change/delete it.

It is doable? I'm out of ideas here. Thanks for any directions.

Comment: @Jaromanda yea I have even wrote that in description of the problem but I silently hoped that somebody smart can make some kind of trick :) I forgot to mention that I need to add HTML message (message that contains HTML tags).

Comment: Answer below should do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [element.insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

```js
for (const a of document.querySelectorAll('body a')) {
    if (a.textContent === '222') {
        a.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<b> - hey this is what we are looking for! </b>');
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="">111</a>
<a href="">222</a>
<a href="">333</a>
```

`afterend` will place the now content just after the `<a>` tag - therefore it won't be *a link*

Comment: yea this is exactly what I needed. Thanks! (but I hoped that 'beforeend' wont be a part of the link it self... cause now I can't simply combine innerHTML :)

Comment: huh? beforeend clearly is inside the element as per documentation - what you really need to show in the question is the **HTML** you have and the **HTML** you want as a result

Comment: I hope it is more clear now (I tried to simplify it to much I guess). So now it is basically editing links by adding HTML content (message) inside them and I can simply just combined their .innerHTML (with all the data - addition tags the link have) - but the problem is, the message should not be linked (i know it is INSIDE link :) I would like not to mess with innerHTML (cutting/duplicating/combining etc.) if it is possible. Another idea is to put message in <A></A> but it is some kind of lame...

Comment: a link inside a link? is that even valid HTML? (no, it isn't)

Comment: yea I'm out of ideas :) I have tried immediately close the link tag and open it near end of the message (so the A tag will close it right after) but this does not work. Every content inside a link tag is wrapped in link tag... even when it is spited - both parts are wrapped in a link.

Comment: I do not add a link I do add other HTML tags (with text), but you are right I add them to the link it self - so the whole becomes a link and I'm looking for something that will add this HTML code (with text) inside a link and not become the link it self (yea funny I know). But I guess there is no magic (legitimate) here that can save me, only some dirty tricks. Thank you for you time @Jaromanda X

Comment: huh? you've accepted the answer ... doesn't it do exactly what you want?

Comment: Don't get me wrong - I guess there is no answer to that question (you can't demand from code that you add to link to not behave as a link), so you reply is probably one of the correct solutions (besides some hacks that resolve the problem but do not validate).

Comment: I seriously don't understand ... please put, in the question, the HTML before you run the code, and the HTML you'd like as a result - perhaps there is an answer, but without seeing definitively what the *input state* and *expected result* is, we can only guess what you want

Comment: I have updated the question, just let my know if something is not straight enough. I have:<a href=x>222<span>span</span></a> I would like to have: <a href=x>222-ADDITIONALCODE(THAT IS NOT  A LINK)<span>span</span></a> (working on innerHTML helps me get everything in chronological order).

Comment: I have done it (!), but the code and answer is BIG. I hope soon I will make an online project then every interested person can see it working and look up for code. Thanks again for your help @Jaromanda X